# How come Google isn't picking up some of my links?

Tags: seo

I have a couple websites on separate servers and IP's that link back with anchor text and all (dofollow), but my webmasters tools dashboard is always missing these links.

Any way to get around this?

Just typical HTML link back to the web design company I run.

Stephanie Nault dot com

Comment: Without a link to the parent and child page where the link resides, we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last cache date of the website you listed was September 12, 2012. Your link wasn't on the page then:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jRts9k1HNjkJ:stephanienault.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: It has been on there for a long time, probably 6 months.

Comment: Interesting:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jRts9k1HNjkJ:stephanienault.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Comment: Thanks for that, could be the footer reset when I switched VPS's